# How To Create And Start Docker Container with specific port, detached mode using docker-java

Tags: docker, docker-java

I want to create and run docker using docker java client. I want running something like this :

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:2.53.0
```

How to implement this command on docker-java client? Here is my code so far :

```
CreateContainerResponse response = dockerClient.createContainerCmd("selenium/hub")
               .withName(name)
               .exec();
```

Actually IDK how to specify -d (for running in background). and -p. 
please help me. sorry I am new in Docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution... if someone find a better one please post in here. I already modify the code to be like this :

```
  ExposedPort tcp4444 = ExposedPort.tcp(4444);
   Ports portBindings = new Ports();
   portBindings.bind(tcp4444,Ports.Binding.bindPort(4444));

   CreateContainerResponse response = dockerClient.
           createContainerCmd("selenium/hub")
           .withName(name)
           .withImage("selenium/hub:"+version)
           .withExposedPorts(tcp4444)
           .withPortBindings(portBindings)
           .withAttachStderr(false)
           .withAttachStdin(false)
           .withAttachStdout(false)
           .exec();`
```

Comment: It looks like this is out of date again. `withPortBindings` was removed from the create container command. Any chance you know the new syntax?

Answer (score 7):

docker-java version 3.1.0 has moved the `withPortBindings` method from `CreateContainerCmd` class to the `HostConfig` class.

Here is the updated way to do it:

```
ExposedPort tcp4444 = ExposedPort.tcp(4444);
Ports portBindings = new Ports();
portBindings.bind(tcp4444, Ports.Binding.bindPort(4444));

// create container from image
CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd("selenium/hub:2.53.0")
            .withExposedPorts(tcp4444)
            .withHostConfig(newHostConfig()
                    .withPortBindings(portBindings))
            .withName("selenium-hub")
            .exec();

// start the container
dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container.getId()).exec();
```

As a side note, I had to go look at the unit tests in the docker-java repository in order to find how to do this.  It seems that is the place to go to find working examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can use hostconfig like below to say bind port 1234 (equivalent to -p 1234:1234)

```
HostConfig hostConfig = HostConfig.newHostConfig().withPortBindings(PortBinding.parse("1234:1234"));
dockerClient.createContainerCmd(..).withHostConfig(hostConfig);
```

Answer (score 2):

docker-java has a nice wiki on https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/wiki. Searching for "port" got me this:

> Create new Docker container and start it with exposed ports
>
> ```
> ExposedPort tcp22 = ExposedPort.tcp(22);
> ExposedPort tcp23 = ExposedPort.tcp(23);
>
> Ports portBindings = new Ports();
> portBindings.bind(tcp22, Ports.Binding(11022));
> portBindings.bind(tcp23, Ports.Binding(11023));
>
> CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd("busybox")
>    .withCmd("true")
>    .withExposedPorts(tcp22, tcp23)
>    .withPortBindings(portBindings)
>    .exec();
> ```

I looked at some tests in docker-java, and it looks like you only did half the work for running a container, because you only *created* the container and didn't *start* it. Based on what I see in this test (https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/069987852c842e3bba85ed3325a8877c36f9e87f/src/test/java/com/github/dockerjava/core/command/ExecStartCmdImplTest.java#L69), your code should look something like this:

```
ExposedPort tcp4444 = ExposedPort.tcp(4444);

Ports portBindings = new Ports();
portBindings.bind(tcp4444, Ports.Binding(4444));

// Create the container (it will not be running)
CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient.createContainerCmd("selenium/hub")
    .withName(name)
    .withExposedPorts(tcp4444)
    .withPortBindings(portBindings)
    .exec();

// Actually run the container
dockerClient.startContainerCmd(container).exec();
```

As far as I can tell, there's no reason to explicitly run it in detached mode because it will be started asynchronously by default.

Comment: thank you already tried this.. I dont find this method : withDetach(true). that's why I am confused. now my code looks like this : 
`ExposedPort tcp4444 = ExposedPort.tcp(4444);
       Ports portBindings = new Ports();
       portBindings.bind(tcp4444,Ports.Binding.bindPort(4444));
       
       CreateContainerResponse response = dockerClient.
               createContainerCmd("selenium/hub")
               .withName(name)
               .withExposedPorts(tcp4444)
               .exec();`

Comment: It looks like this is out of date again.  `withPortBindings` was removed from the create container command.  Any chance you know the new syntax?